# use transactionScope on a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope

did anyone used TransactionScope when adding ojects to a list of objects?
Something like:

```
     using Transaction
     {  
        try
        { var a = method();
          list.add(a)
          transaction.commit;
        }
        catch exception(Ex)
        {
          transaction.rollback();
        }
     }
```

Should work just fine ?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you should use TransactionScope to retrieve data only. Unless you do some modification when you called `method()`, I think you may remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransactionScope` requires cooperation from anything that wants to be transacted. Database APIs usually cooperate and are willing to be transacted. None of the built-in data structures cares (or knows) about `TransactionScope` so this will simply have no effect.

The catch+rollback is a common mistake, just delete that code.